# What does internally hosted means

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have built a site in WordPress and the client wants to control things through WordPress but he wants the live version to be static for which someone told me to use StaticPress plugin.

He would like to have the WordPress version internally hosted and the live version would be static. He further wants to update things using WordPress and then push it so that the live static version gets updated automatically.

I would like to know that what does internally hosted means how this can be achieved. Let me know if my question is unclear, I'll either update it or reply to clarify you.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

internally hosted means that you have your system running inside the company infrastructure.
So it means that your client want to have wordpress installed on a server managed by the company.

Comment: Can this be done through the client's PC as the site does not possess any major functionality and why there would be a need to keep that system open 24 hours. He would be updating things occasionally and will push the files through the plugin in order to update the static version which is already hosted by bluehost.

Comment: One more thing which I was thinking is that I would upload the WP site on the live server. Let me explain this lets say their domain name is www.jinglebell.com so would it work if I make the wp version live on this domain with any extension from where the client would be able to access the wp and whenever they edit something they have to push it through the plugin so that the static version gets updated on the original domain which is www.jinglebell.com Can this be a fine solution?

Comment: Yes, wp can be hosted on the clients PC. there are many way to achieve what you want, my guess is that the most suitable is that you deploy a copy of the WP on production using FTP.

Comment: I know all the uploading stuff but for this I am confused a bit that how I am going to deploy this as the client want to have the wp in his PC and the cashed site live from where no one can access its WordPress back end.

Comment: Would u b able to send me something so that I come know that how I would be doing it. Thanks.

Comment: No sorry I dont have time for this. Basically you need to set up WP on the client machine (for example using WAMP) and on the production server. you would need to configure also an Ftp server on the production server and an FTP client on the PC to sync the static site.  Please do some research on how to achieve each of the steps.

Comment: You got me wrong man what u have told is enough for me to do it.

Comment: Great, I am glade it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

It basically means that he wants the live version to be a cached (static) version of the full database-queriable WordPress that is hosted on a local/slave server. See Master/Slave Server Relationships: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master/slave_%28technology%29

It is used to allow for high-volume traffic and not have it shut down the server from heavy amounts of querying. (Otherwise, each user-visit would have 1+ queries to the server for every page, post, and plugin loaded).

There are plugins that assist with caching, CDNs to assist with content delivery and put up firewalls against known spammers - but it sounds like this client knows specifically what he wants (StaticPress & Master-Slave Server Relationship).

Comment: This is a third party project so yea the client known everything and he himself is an experienced developer but the main party is really non-technical.

Can this be done through the client's PC as the site does not possess any major functionality and why there would be a need to keep  that system open 24 hours. He would be updating things occasionally and will push the files through the plugin in order to update the static version which is already hosted by bluehost.

Comment: One more thing which I was thinking is that I would upload the WP site on the live server. Let me explain this

lets say their domain name is www.jinglebell.com so would it work if I  make the wp version live on this domain with any extension from where the client would be able to access the wp and whenever they edit something they have to push it through the plugin so that the static version gets updated on the original domain which is www.jinglebell.com

Can this be a fine solution?